# How to remove a specific element from an array which is inside of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, state

I am learning how to manage application state via a shopping list exercise. Per the instructions, I have an array inside an object where I store any items I add:

```
var state = {
    items: []
};
```

To modify `state` I use this function:

```
var addItem = function(state, item) {
state.items.push(item);
};
```

which is called later via an event listener (and added to the DOM via `renderList`, not shown here):

```
$('#js-shopping-list-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    addItem(state, $('#shopping-list-entry').val());
    renderList(state, $('.shopping-list'));
});
```

How can I remove a specific item from the array inside my `state` object? Essentially I want to reverse the sequence above when the user clicks on `<button class="shopping-item-delete">`.

Here's a demo of the final solution: https://thinkful-ed.github.io/shopping-list-solution/

## HTML

```
<body>

  <div class="container">

    <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
      <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
      <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
      <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>

    <ul class="shopping-list">
    <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function as follows:

```
var deleteItem = function(state, item) {
    var index = state.items.indexOf(item);
    if (index > -1) {
        state.items.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

Note that the method `indexOf` is not supported in Internet Explorer 7 and 8.

Comment: Surely we can let go IE 7 and 8 right? it's almost 2017! lol, anyways polyfill can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the item you can use. You can determine the index by value of item

```
state.items.splice(indexOfItemToRemove, 1);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to remove elements from Arrays:

[`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) will remove the first item from the beginning

[`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) will remove the last item from the end.

[`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) allows you to remove an element at a desired location

Note that all of these will modify the original array (they work "in-place") as opposed to returning a new array.

Answer (score 0):

You may loop over the items

```
var removeItem = function(state, item) {
  for(var i = state.items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(state.items[i] === item) {
       state.items.splice(i, 1);
       break;
    }
  }
};
```